# Method to get the count of an element in an array within specified range

Tags: c#, arrays, vb.net

If I have an ArrayList called holder: `{2,3,3,5,4,7,1,7,8,4}`. Let say I wanted to find the count of certain element's occurrence in the above array within a certain range, I have these function:

> In VB.Net:

```
Private Function getValInRange(ByVal lowerVal As Integer, ByVal upperVal As Integer, ByVal holder As ArrayList) As Integer
        Dim count As Integer = 0
        For Each item As Integer In holder
            If (item <= upperVal AndAlso item >= lowerVal) Then
                count = count + 1
            End If
        Next
        Return count
End Function
```

> In C#:

```
private int getValInRange(int lowerVal, int upperVal, ArrayList holder)
{
    int count = 0;
    foreach (int item in holder)
    {
        if ((item <= upperVal && item >= lowerVal))
        {
            count = count + 1;
        }
    }

    return count;
}
```

So, when I query `count = getValInRange(3,5,holder)`, I shall get a return of **5**

I know the above function will be able to satisfy my needs, but I wonder if there is already a built in function that I can use. I plan to clean up my code and learn at the same time. Thanks a lot...

Comment: Do you have to use the non-generic `ArrayList`? That's been somewhat-obsolete since 2005. If you could use some implementation of `IEnumerable<int>` (e.g. `List<int>` or `int[]`) it would be much simpler. I'd also suggest following .NET naming conventions - I'd call the method `CountValuesInRange` for example.

Comment: @Jon Skeet I am using ArrayList all the time. But you suggestion to use different implementation is good. Maybe shall start to use that from my next attempt onwards. Anyway, I prefer to not to have a separate method `CountValuesInRange`

Comment: "I am using ArrayList all the time" - I'd stop doing that if I were you. I wouldn't wait, I'd learn about generic collections *right now*.

Comment: @JonSkeet thanks for your suggestion man. I learned something new

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think there is such a built-in method in .NET Core, but you *can* write this more concisely, using `Enumerable.Where`.

```
 holder.Cast<int>().Where(x => x <= upperLimit && x >= lowerLimit).Count()
```

`ArrayList` is actually obsolete. If you don't have to stick with it, try changing to a `List<int>`. That way, you don't need the call to `Cast`:

```
 holder.Where(x => x <= upperLimit && x >= lowerLimit).Count()
```

Alternatively,

```
 holder.Count(x => x <= upperLimit && x >= lowerLimit)
```

The `x => ...` thing, if you didn't know, is called a lambda expression, learn more about them [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/statements-expressions-operators/lambda-expressions).

There are lots of other cool methods that help you with dealing with `IEnumerable<T>` in the `System.Linq` namespace! This cool collection of helper methods is called [Language INtegrated Query (LINQ)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/linq/).

Comment: You can write it shorter if you put lambda inside `Count` and remove `Where`

Comment: OP also asked for VB, so `holder.Sum(Function(x) If(x >= lowerVal AndAlso x <= upperVal, 1, 0))` as .Count in VB 15.0 (2017) doesn't accept a lambda. Or just the .Where....Count version.

Answer (score 4):

If you use `List<int>`, or any other `IEnumerable<int>`, Linq has the `Count` extension

```
private int getValInRange(int lowerVal, int upperVal, List<int> holder)
{
    return holder.Count(item => item <= upperVal && item >= lowerVal);
}
```

Edit: As @MarcGravell suggested, you can also cast the `ArrayList` to `IEnumerable`

```
private int getValInRange(int lowerVal, int upperVal, ArrayList holder)
{
    return holder.Cast<int>().Count(item => item <= upperVal && item >= lowerVal);
}
```

Comment: Note you can still use this with `ArrayList`, but you'd need to use `.Cast<int>().Count(...)` - although I agree that moving away from `ArrayList` is hugely desirable

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest to use LINQ and change that `ArrayList` to `IEnumerable`, however using  `IEnumerable<int>` is more preferred.

```
private int GetValInRange(int lowerVal, int upperVal, IEnumerable holder)
    {
        return holder.Cast<int>().Count(item => item <= upperVal && item >= lowerVal);
    }
```

Comment: Unfortunately using ArrayList currently